# Mongodb sort by either of two fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

Is there a way to sort by two fields at the same time in mongodb?
So let's say we have the following documents in the collection:

```
{ id: 'name1', last_1: 5, last_2: 2 },
{ id: 'name2', last_1: 1, last_2: 9 },
{ id: 'name3', last_1: 4, last_2: 3 }
```

I want it to be sorted in descending order, checking both last_1 and last_2, so the result would be:
document2 (9 in last_2), document1 (5 in last_1), document3 (4 in last_1). I also need to know which field it is in the result.
My current aggregation looks like this:

```
{ $group:
      { _id: { id: '$name' },
        last_1: { $last: '$field1' },
        last_2: { $last: '$field2' },
      }
      },
      { $sort : { /* don't know what to put in here */ } },
      { $limit: some_limit }
```

UPD: I'll probably have to remove sort/limit at all and use some custom node function for that, because it looks like I can't achieve it using just mongo, especially because the additional requirement would be to list the same document twice if both its fields are bigger than in the other documents.

Comment: It is almost impossible to tell without your own input which field should take precedence in this case. As such the only way currently is to assign weightings to these fields for a single sort field via the aggregation framework

Comment: Neither of them should be taking precedence, again, after the group stage I have, say 5 documents, with last values of two fields and I want mongo to take all 10 values (5 docs * 2 last values), sort them and arrange those documents based on the first 5 values after sorting.

Comment: well you say in your example that doc 2 should take last_2 as precedence since that is 9 whereas doc1 should take last_1 as precedence since that is 5, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this,

## 1

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: {name: 1, field1: 1, field2: 1}},
    {$group: {_id: '$name', field_1: { $last: '$field1' }, field_2: { $last: '$field2' }}},
    {$project: {name: 1, field_1: 1, field_2: 1, cmp: { $cmp: ['$field_2', '$field_1'] } }},
    {$sort: { cmp: -1, field_1: -1, field_2: -1 }}
])
```

## 2

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: {name: 1, field1: 1, field2: 1}},
    {$group: {_id: '$name', field_1: { $last: '$field1' }, field_2: { $last: '$field2' }}},
    {$project: {
        name: 1, 
        field_1: 1, 
        field_2: 1, 
        largest: { $cond: [ {$gt: ['$field_2', '$field_1']}, '$field_2', '$field_1'] }    
    }},
    {$sort: { largest: -1 }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement being to `sort` your documents in the collection based on the fields, `last_1` and `last_2`,  whichever is largest among them can be aggregated as below:

- Project an extra field which holds the greater value among `last_1` and
  `last_2`.
- Based on this field `sort` the records in `descending` order.
- Then `project` the required fields.

The aggregation code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{"id":"$id",
           "last_1":1,
           "last_2":1,
           "sortField":{$cond:[
                               {$gt:["$last_1","$last_2"]},
                               "$last_1",
                               "$last_2"]}}},
{$sort:{"sortField":-1}},
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "id":"$id",
           "last_1":1,
           "last_2":1}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how it ended up, I was afraid it'd be too slow in compare with something mongodb-native, but it's actually not that bad:

```
Test.aggregate(
        [
          { $match:
          {'modified': { $gte: settings.period } }
          },

          { $group:
          { _id: { name: '$name' },
            last_1: { $last: '$field_1' },
            last_2: { $last: '$field_2' },
          }
          }
        ],

        function (err, result) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          else {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              var obj = result[i];
              arr.push({ id: obj._id, sort: obj.last_1 });
              arr.push({ id: obj._id, sort: obj.last_2 });
            }
            arr.sort(compare).reverse();
            arr = arr.slice(0, settings.limit);
            var arr2 = [];
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              var id = arr[i].id;
              var element = result.filter(function(element) {
                return element._id == id;
              });
              arr2.push(element[0]);
            }
            callback(null, arr2);
          }
        });
      );

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.sort < b.sort)
    return -1;
  if (a.sort > b.sort)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `mongodb native` ? You have ended up doing everything on the client side. It is not the way to do it when you can do it on the server side.

Comment: @BatScream, It is my server side.

Comment: No its not. You have handled everything in your callback function.

Comment: @BatScream, This is nodejs and this is my server code, what client side are you talking about?

Comment: I mentioned about the database server and not your app server. By the client i meant your app server. It is the one firing a query and acts as a client to the database server.

Comment: @BatScream, unfortunately I have to do this, as I can't get the necessary result with just aggregation.